# Slow multiprocessing queue

Tags: python-3.x, flask, multiprocessing, gunicorn

I'm trying to run things in parallel with multiprocessing in Python. I'm using gunicorn.

I have a multiprocessing process for each database query that gets initialized outside not in a flask request handler. I use multiprocessing queues for the request objects and for the response objects.

Here's the code:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def task1(arg1):
    # database query
    time.sleep(5)
    return "RESULT1"

def task2(arg1):
    # database query
    time.sleep(5)
    return "RESULT2"

def task3(arg3):
    # database query
    time.sleep(5)
    return "RESULT3"

def worker(q, r):
    running = True
    while running:
        work, args = q.get()
        print("Received " + work)
        if work == None:
            running = False
            continue
        result = globals()[work](*args)
        print("Done " + work)
        r.put(result)


queue1 = multiprocessing.Queue()
queue2 = multiprocessing.Queue()
queue3 = multiprocessing.Queue()

r1 = multiprocessing.Queue()
r2 = multiprocessing.Queue()
r3 = multiprocessing.Queue()

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(queue1, r1))
p1.daemon = True
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(queue2, r2))
p2.daemon = True
p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(queue3, r3))
p3.daemon = True

p1.start()
p2.start()
p3.start()

# the following are in my flask web request handler, I run three database queries in parallel

queue1.put(("task1", (0,)))
queue2.put(("task2", (0,)))
queue3.put(("task3", (0,)))

# and get the responses (blocking on each one)

print(r1.get())
print(r2.get())
print(r3.get())
```

This example code works. It should return:

```
Received task2
Received task1
Received task3
Done task2
Done task3
Done task1
RESULT1
RESULT2
RESULT3
```

My real code looks the same as this but it runs in Gunicorn.

The bug I have is that the 3rd queue item (the `queue3.put(("task3", (0,)))`) takes a very long time to be received by the process and I don't understand why.

**if I reorder the queue items, it's always the third item that hangs, so it's not the database queries**

It takes so long that Gunicorn times out. Eventually I get a response from the worker down the worker queue, but by that time gunicorn has timed out.

I think it's some thing to do with multiprocessing Queue buffering but I see no way of configuring buffering with multiprocessing.

Here's the output:

```
Received task1
Received task2
Done task1
Done task2
[2020-07-05 16:48:49 +0100] [26705] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:26707)
Received task3
Done task3
```

Notice how I don't get any output for responses.

Comment: How many gunicorn processes are you launching?

Comment: Is there a reason to omit `p1.join()` et al.? That's liable to cause a slow resource leak.